# Tensorflow doesn't allow for training data to be used in (features,targets) style?

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

I have `data` that is a ndarray containing features and targets with different dimensions respectively. This seems to give tensorflow problems.

If I have a function:

```
def cost(self,data):
     return self.sess.run(self.cost_function, feed_dict={self.input:data[:,0], self.targets:data[:,1]})
```

This results in `ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence`.

It seems to be because `feed_dict` is not recognizing my inputs as numpy arrays. I think this is because features and targets have different dimensions and `ndarray` has problems with that; if I have `data` with 100 pairs then its shape is `(100,2)`. If I then slice it: `data[:,0].shape=(100,)` and `data[:,1].shape=(100,)`, so the length of the feature/target vectors is not recognized even after slicing.

I've got around the problem by splitting `data` up beforehand into `feats` and `targs`, who's shapes are returned correctly.

My question is, is this normal - is this supposed to be like this? Or am I just doing something wrong? It would be nicer to just work with `data` instead of passing two variables around all the time.

edit:

```
self.input = tf.placeholder("float",shape=[None,39])
self.targets = tf.placeholder("float",shape=[None,949])
```

The dimensions of `data` should be self-explanatory.

Comment: It is not very clear without knowing what `self.input` and `self.targets` are. You could also debug `data` (print for us the dimensions of the array or show some generating code).  If `features` and `targets` have different shapes and `data = [featues, targets]` then there is no way you could slice `data[:, 0]` without another error.

Comment: Your last sentence answers my question. I'm surprised that's the case though since it means unless one is using an Autoencoder one always has to pass features and targets around in separate variables. Edited my post with additional info anyways.